# How to create a HashMap with ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to create a HashMap which will look like this

```
key.   value
1.     [[1,2,5][4,5]]
2.     [[12,2][45,54]]
3.     [[1,23][43,25]]
```

I get these values from the user as a ArrayList.
How do I add the values to the map

i declared tha map as

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I tried to insert the value like

```
map.put(i,new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>(userInput));
```

but I get a error since userInput is just ArrayList

Comment: What do you mean by, "userInput is just ArrayList"? Can you show the declaration of `userInput`?

Comment: ArrayList<Interger> userInput = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 2):

This works when working with `java 11`:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      List<Integer> inner = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
      List<List<Integer>> outer = List.of(inner, inner);
      
      Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map = Map.of(5, outer);
      
      System.out.println(map); // {5=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]}
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I add a new value to the map, Ex :{5=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4],[4,3,5]]}

Comment: using `put` the same way